Cant set 2560x1440 resolution in ubuntu 2204 vm hosted by Win 11 HyperV
After some fiddling. I am able to add 2560x1600 into the selection. What I really want is 2560x1440 because that's my monitor's native resolution.
Current selection:

Commands issued at host:
set-vmvideo -vmname vm1 -horizontalresolution:3840  -verticalresolution:2160 -resolutiontype single

If I use set-vmvideo 2560x1440, in Ubuntu VM the highest resolution showing up is 2048x1152, so I tried to issue higher resolution from the host and it is giving me 2560x1600.
Commands inside Ubuntu 2204 VM:
cvt -reduced 2560 1440 60
sudo xrandr --newmode "cvt output modeline"
sudo xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "2560x1440_60.00"

But I am unable to get 2560x1440.
